# How to open Edge browser in protractor for edgeHTML version 18

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, edge-chromium

I tried all the solutions that are mentioned, but I am not able to get Microsoft Edge (HTML version 18) in Windows 10.

I downloaded the web driver using the below command on my personal PC and copied it to my work system under the node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium.

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

On my personal system, I can run the script by using

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'MircorsoftEdge' ,
},
```

But after copying the webdriver manually to my work system and trying to run the script, it's failing with the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto EDGE > setting  and scroll down:

[image]

Here note the edge html version , that is the version for which we have to download the driver for.

The below command (for downloading webdriver for edge html version 18) ,

ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

downloads the web driver usually to system32 folder which is already in PATH variable. That's why your protractor scripts work fine in your local system.

*To run it in the other system to which you copied the webdriver, follow any of the below approaches:*

**To start the selenium server manually:**

Open cmd and run below command

```
 webdriver-manager start --edge "<path>"
```

eg:

```
 webdriver-manager start --edge "c:/New Folder/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
```

Now connect to the server using the protractor config file by pointing seleniumAddress to the correct address:

```
exports.config = {

specs: ['test.js'],

seleniumAddress:"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge' ,
 }
```

If selenium is started in port:4444

**Starting selenium server from the script:**

The driver for MicrosoftEdge can be started from the script in two ways

**Method 1: by setting MicrosoftWebDriver.exe path in PATH variable**

1) If your webdriver "MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" is in c:\New Folder, then add "c:\New Folder\" to  Environmental variable PATH

[image]

**Note:** the driver name should be MicrosoftWebDriver.exe

Now you can run the script in edge as :

```
exports.config = {

specs: ['test.js'],

capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge' ,
}
```

you don't have to mention seleniumAddress, the server starts automatically from the script.

**Method 2: By, passing the driver location through jvmArgs**

```
exports.config = {
specs: ['test.js'],


localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    //port:5000, // you can even specify what port to start the server on 
    jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:/New Folder/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],
},

capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge' ,
}
```

**Note:** Don't pass quotest for jvmArgs eg: `'-Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:/New Folder/1.exe"'` is wrong and `'-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=C:/New Folder/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'` is right

Comment: Added to PATH and it worked, Thanks a lot