# Automated testing Edge Chromium with Selenium and javascript returns "Unknown Error"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, edge-chromium

When trying to run Selenium on Windows 10 Edge Chrome version 80, I am getting the following error:

```
Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2626
        throw error;
        ^

WebDriverError: Unknown error
    at parseHttpResponse (Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:536:11)
    at Z:\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[...]
```

I am building it like this:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');

 var service = new edge.ServiceBuilder()
     .setPort(55555)
     .build();

 var options = new edge.Options();
 driver = edge.Driver.createSession(options, service);
```

Does anyone see why this might be happening? Has anyone had success building the driver using the javascript bindings and can share how they were able to do that?

I'm confident that I have the correct version of the Microsoft Edge Driver
UPDATE: Also note that Edge launches, but never begins navigating. The script works fine for all other browsers.

Possible relevant note: I'm running in a VirtualBox VM of Windows 10, but the automation scripts all live on the Z: on my Mac. I have added the z: to my path.

MicrosoftwebDriver is running, too:
[image: Running, too]

Comment: Is the edge driver in path? Did u install the correct driver version ?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42978/how-to-open-edge-browser-in-protractor-for-edgehtml-version-18/42979#42979

Comment: Edge launches, so i am convinced I have the right driver. I'll recheck the path.

Comment: so what's the issue you are facing if edge is opening ?

Comment: let driver = new webdriver.Builder()

    .forBrowser('firefox')

    .setChromeOptions(/* ... */)

    .setFirefoxOptions(/* ... */)

    .build();

Comment: This is the format from the npm documentation

Comment: @PDHide Edge launches, but never begins navigating. I tend to think the problem is with getting the session. It's peculiar because the script works well with just about every other browser and device (Chrome, Firefox, Appium with iOS and Android).

Comment: even your code works fine in my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

```
/* In another command prompt window enter the command:
   msedgedriver.exe --verbose  

   Then run the script as normal in the other command prompt
*/
const Selenium = require("selenium-webdriver");
const BROWSER_NAME = Selenium.Browser.EDGE;
const builder = new Selenium.Builder().forBrowser(BROWSER_NAME)
.withCapabilities({
        "browserName": 'MicrosoftEdge',
        "browserVersion": '81.0',
        "platformName": 'Windows 10',
        'ms:edgeChromium': true
    }).usingServer('http://localhost:9515')

const driver = builder.build()
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify that driver is in PATH:

just open cmd and type the driver name,

[image]

This is the tested code for Edge legacy:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```

**Note**: I have the webdriver in the path, so if C:/tmp/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is the path of your webdriver then add c:/tmp/ to path

I checked your code even thats working:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');

 var service = new edge.ServiceBuilder()
     .setPort(55555)
     .build();

 var options = new edge.Options();
 driver = edge.Driver.createSession(options, service);

(async function a(){


    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
    await driver.quit();
})()
```

Comment: you can verify that drriver is present by opening cmd and typing the name

Comment: I've verified that it is present. "Listening on http://localhost:17556/"